# Chart.js Line-Chart with different Labels for each Dataset

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) you can create line charts and for that you have to privde labels and datasets. for example:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
```

The Problem here is that you have a fix amount of labels (7 in this case) and you also need to provide 7 data entries for each dataset. Now what if you have an unknown amount of labels and data entries?

What if one data entry contains a number and a time:

```
Entry {
    number: 127
    time: 10:00
}
```

What if you want to show all times on the X-Axis and all Numbers on the Y-Axis sorted by the time on the X-Axis. Is that possible with Chart.js?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: Still nothing? It seems like we are missing something here, it's a common user case.

Comment: Try making the value of the missing data entries null.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a battle with this today too.
You need to get a bit more specific with your dataset. In a line chart "datasets" is an array with each element of the array representing a line on your chart.  Chart.js is actually really flexible here once you work it out. You can tie a line (a dataset element) to an x-axis and/or a y-axis, each of which you can specify in detail.

In your case if we stick with a single line on the chart and you want the "time" part of the entry to be along the bottom (the x-axis) then all your times could go into the "labels" array and your "number" would be pin-pointed on the y-axis.  To keep it simple without specifying our own scales with x and y axes and given this data:

```
var MyData = [{time:"10:00", number: "127"},
              {time:"11:00", number: "140"},
              {time:"12:00", number: "135"},
              {time:"13:00", number: "122"}];
```

You could set up the "data" property of your chart to be:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",

            // Insert styling, colors etc here

            data: [{x: "10:00", y: 127},
                   {x: "11:00", y: 140},
                   {x: "12:00", y: 135},
                   {x: "13:00", y: 122}]
        }
    ]};
```

Note that the data array is now a bit more specific with each element of data plotting itself on the x-axis by referencing one of the labels rather than just being a raw number. You can now put another dataset object in the datasets array following this pattern and have two lines, obviously give your lines different colours and names ("label").

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there are some square braces here where there should be curly braces. `[x: "10:00", y: 127]` isn't valid js

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me... used null values instead.

Comment: I cannot understand how this answer the question. Here there's one `labels` thing, it doesn't represent multiple datasets but only the first one.

If dataset 1 has labels [1..10] and the dataset 2 has labels [2..10] then how can this be plotted?

MpAndroidCharts and danielgindi/Charts solve this.

Answer (score 15):

I found a really good solution here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3953

Basically, you can add in your own 'labels' property to each dataset and leverage it in the callbacks for the xAxes labels, tooltips, or whatever you like.

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            backgroundColor: [
                'green',
                'yellow',
                'red',
                'purple',
                'blue',
            ],
            labels: [
                'green',
                'yellow',
                'red',
                'purple',
                'blue',
            ]
        }, {
            data: [6, 7, 8],
            backgroundColor: [
                'black',
                'grey',
                'lightgrey'
            ],
            labels: [
                'black',
                'grey',
                'lightgrey'
            ],
        },]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                    var index = tooltipItem.index;
                    return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What's important here is this piece:

```
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                    var index = tooltipItem.index;
                    return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me i can use the tooltip in options and add the labels in it as well!

Answer (score 4):

Since there's a number of questions in your post, I'll try to help out with at least some of them. In the case of your Entry model with a number and a time you should create a scattered graph. Here you define data objects with x and y values as shown in my example below. It requires that each entry x has a corresponding y.
Have a look at the scatter chart.
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts

```
var d = new Date();
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{
                x: new Date().setDate(d.getDate()-5),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: new Date(),
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: new Date().setDate(d.getDate()5),
                y: 5
            }]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        format: "HH:mm",
                        unit: 'hour',
                        unitStepSize: 2,
                        displayFormats: {
                            'minute': 'HH:mm', 
                            'hour': 'HH:mm'
                        },
                        tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please give an explanation of how this answers the question

Comment: Check the scatter-line-charts link provided in answer.

Comment: this answer is similar to the "use google" type of answers. It doesn't answers the question.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: This answer completely answered my question how to add datasets with independent labels. Just read the code and answer will punch you into face.

Comment: It actually DOES answer the question perfectly!