# How to provide empty values for Chart.js data?

Tags: javascript, object, chart.js

Looking at [this](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/#2-line-chart) example, it seems that `labels.length`and each `data.length` must be equal.

What if I want to leave some of the elements undefined? For example:

```
labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],

data1: [86,114,10 ,106,107,13,133,221,100,2478]

data2: [282,350,411,502]
```

As you can see, `data2` is defined only for the first 4 intervals. I want to draw 2 lines, but the second one "shorter" than the first one.

Or even better another data which is defined only on a subset of the given range, like:

```
 data3: [null,null,null,null,107,13,133,null,null,null]
```

Comment: That makes no sense for a line chart, you'd have empty sections of the line - perhaps you can explain the context and reasoning a little more

Comment: @DarrenSweeney see my updated post

Comment: This is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101859/chart-js-line-chart-with-different-labels-for-each-dataset) which has some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a label to have empty data, you can pass a `null` value to the corresponding data index, but it will be treated as a `0`.

For example:

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["dD 1", "dD 2", "dD 3", "dD 4", "dD 5", "dD 6", "dD 7", "dD 8", "dD 9", "dD 10"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(0,60,100,1)",
    strokeColor: "black",
    data: [125, null, 12, 52, 65, 20, null, 40, 70, 45]
  }]
}
```

This is a Live working snippet:

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["dD 1", "dD 2", "dD 3", "dD 4", "dD 5", "dD 6", "dD 7", "dD 8", "dD 9", "dD 10"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(0,60,100,1)",
    strokeColor: "black",
    data: [125, null, 12, 52, 65, 20, null, 40, 70, 45]
  }]
}

var index = 11;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  barValueSpacing: 2
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Chart.js Responsive Bar Chart Demo</h2>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```