# ChartJs showing wrong labels of data (x-axis dates)

Tags: php, html, chart.js

I have a ChartJs Chart, below is the code

```
chartColor = "#FFFFFF";
var ctx = document.getElementById('bigDashboardChart').getContext("2d");

var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, '#80b6f4');
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, chartColor);

var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 50);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24)");

gradientFill2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
gradientFill2.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
gradientFill2.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB('#edd505', 0.4));

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['2020-02-07','2020-02-08','2020-02-09','2020-02-10','2020-02-11','2020-02-12','2020-02-13'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Ujani Total Water",
      borderColor: chartColor,
      pointBorderColor: chartColor,
      pointBackgroundColor: "#1e3d60",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#1e3d60",
      pointHoverBorderColor: chartColor,
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 7,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 5,
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: gradientFill,
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [{ 'x' : '2020-02-07', 'y' : 16483111.23},{ 'x' : '2020-02-08', 'y' : 5624132.01},{ 'x' : '2020-02-09', 'y' : 9800147.12},{ 'x' : '2020-02-10', 'y' : 17204617.82},{ 'x' : '2020-02-11', 'y' : 19318882.05},{ 'x' : '2020-02-12', 'y' : 6291494.27},{ 'x' : '2020-02-13', 'y' : 10536864.88}]
    },
    {
      label: "Chandani Total Water",
      borderColor: "#edd505",
      pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#FFF",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 7,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 5,
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: gradientFill2,
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [{ 'x' : '2020-02-11', 'y' : 744864.1},{ 'x' : '2020-02-12', 'y' : 544.93},{ 'x' : '2020-02-13', 'y' : 1564922.77}]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      titleFontColor: '#333',
      bodyFontColor: '#666',
      bodySpacing: 4,
      xPadding: 12,
      mode: "nearest",
      intersect: 0,
      position: "nearest"
    },
    legend: {
      position: "top",
      fillStyle: "#FFF",
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked : false,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)",
          fontStyle: "bold",
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          padding: 10
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: true,
          drawBorder: false,
          display: true,
          color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
          zeroLineColor: "transparent"
          }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          display: false,

        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero : true,
          padding: 10,
          min: 0,
          fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)",
          fontStyle: "bold"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

You can see the image as well, **the date shown in both the image for the first point is same but actually the date for yellow dataset starts at 2020-02-11 on ward.**

Or is this because I'm not implementing the charts with multiple datasets properly? Any help is appreciated. Also please let me know if any other info is needed.

**Note : this only 1 chart, I have just shown the 2 images to shown the wrong label of starting points.**

[image: Wrong label image]

Update : tried adding "Labels" to individual data sets like this after going through other Stack Overflow and other answer.

```
 {
      label: "Chandani Total Water",
      labels : ['2020-02-11','2020-02-12','2020-02-13'],
      borderColor: "#edd505",
      pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#FFF",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 7,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 5,
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: gradientFill2,
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [{ 'x' : '2020-02-11', 'y' : 744864.1},{ 'x' : '2020-02-12', 'y' : 544.93},{ 'x' : '2020-02-13', 'y' : 1564922.77}]
    }
```

Comment: Your html code?

Comment: there is nothing much in the html part. Just 1 line <canvas id="bigDashboardChart" ></canvas>, thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

To do so, add the following to your `xAxis` inside the chart `options`.

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'day'
    },
    ...
```

> Please note that Chart.js uses Moment.js for the functionality of the
>   time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
var chartColor = "#FFFFFF";
var ctx = document.getElementById('bigDashboardChart').getContext("2d");

var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, '#80b6f4');
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, chartColor);

var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 50);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24)");

var gradientFill2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
gradientFill2.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
gradientFill2.addColorStop(1, "rgba(237, 213, 5, 0.4)");

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['2020-02-07', '2020-02-08', '2020-02-09', '2020-02-10', '2020-02-11', '2020-02-12', '2020-02-13'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Ujani Total Water",
        borderColor: chartColor,
        pointBorderColor: chartColor,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#1e3d60",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#1e3d60",
        pointHoverBorderColor: chartColor,
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 7,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 5,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [{
          'x': '2020-02-07',
          'y': 16483111.23
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-08',
          'y': 5624132.01
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-09',
          'y': 9800147.12
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-10',
          'y': 17204617.82
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-11',
          'y': 19318882.05
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-12',
          'y': 6291494.27
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-13',
          'y': 10536864.88
        }]
      },
      {
        label: "Chandani Total Water",
        borderColor: "#edd505",
        pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#edd505",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#FFF",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 7,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 5,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientFill2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [{
          'x': '2020-02-11',
          'y': 744864.1
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-12',
          'y': 544.93
        }, {
          'x': '2020-02-13',
          'y': 1564922.77
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      titleFontColor: '#333',
      bodyFontColor: '#666',
      bodySpacing: 4,
      xPadding: 12,
      mode: "nearest",
      intersect: 0,
      position: "nearest"
    },
    legend: {
      position: "top",
      fillStyle: "#FFF",
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)",
          fontStyle: "bold",
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          padding: 10
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: true,
          drawBorder: false,
          display: true,
          color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
          zeroLineColor: "transparent"
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          padding: 10,
          min: 0,
          fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)",
          fontStyle: "bold"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="bigDashboardChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello, after adding this to xAxis, the chart is not showing at all.

Comment: Did you maybe forger a comma?

Comment: no actually, double checked that, Also I trying this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101859/chart-js-line-chart-with-different-labels-for-each-dataset as it matches my case.

Comment: I updated my answer with a runnable code snippet that should illustrate that my proposal works.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the explanation. Though I included moment.js file searately as I'm using  ready made template and don't want to mess with other functions. Thanks.