# Chart.js: Label each dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've been trying to make chart.js have a label for each dataset but the first label is located underneath both datasets and the second on an empty area of the chart.

```js
var powerChart = new Chart(powerCanvas, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Volts", "Amperes"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Volts", // This bar should have this label underneath itself
        data: [24.78], // Initial value, will be overwritten
      },
      {
        label: "Amperes", // This bar should have this label underneath itself
        data: [14.51],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {},
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/w20c3tru/2/ for what I have tried and a working example.
Note: I tried to follow
[Chart.js Line-Chart with different Labels for each Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101859/chart-js-line-chart-with-different-labels-for-each-dataset)
but could not see any difference.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code is trimmed to minimum now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have it working as I want thanks to a hint by a user who separated the data in x and y sections

```
Code on jsFiddle
```

Full working example here:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peak_/qn31u78x/)

Answer (score 3):

Note the comments below:

```js
var powerChart = new Chart(powerCanvas,
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data:
        {
            labels: ['Volts', 'Amperes'],
            datasets:
                [
                    {
                        label: 'Value',       // This is actually the label that shows up when you hover over a bar
                        data: [24.78, 14.51]  // NOTE: Number of labels defined above should equal number of values here
                    },
                ]
        },
        options:
        {
        }
    }
);
```

Edit:

```js
data:
{
    labels: ['Volts', 'Amperes'],
    datasets:
        [
            {
                data: [24.78, 14.51],  // Volts and amperes, respectively
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: ['#0000e0', '#e00000'],  // Border colors for volts and amperes, respectively
    
            },
        ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the datasets have different span and units, that's why I wanted to keep them separate. If there is no other solution I might have to rethink the whole setup. 
I tried to upvote your answer but I am too new here to be allowed that.

Comment: You can check out other charts except bar chart, maybe they might suit your needs. I do not know exactly what you're trying to implement, but you can tinker around these hurdles to fit your needs :)

Comment: Implementing a chart that will get data from my power meter and display energy, power, voltage and current on a webpage.

Comment: Are energy, power, voltage and current all integers? If so, you can just represent them as an array (with predetermined indexes according to your label indexes, like in my answer)... Just saw your updated fiddle link, check out the edit, maybe you're looking for something like this?

Comment: No, they must be floats by my original design. I'm new to fiddle, please elaborate on "check out the edit, maybe you're looking for something like this?"

Comment: My bad, I meant to ask if they were single values. Yes, floats should work perfectly fine with bar charts.

Comment: That's exactly what I intended to make, immediate single values displayed on the chart.